# Representation for circumferences intersection

Tags: geometric-interpretation

I'm trying to write a formula that represents the intersections points for $n$ circumferences. All of these circumferences intersect them to each other. Is there a good representation to explicit this concept?

Comment: There might or might not be a good representation for whatever you want, but there's a catch: first _you_  must put your problem in words, so that we could get an idea of what's going on. As it stands now, we can't.

Comment: I have n circumferences and I want represent the intersections among them, nothing else. The problem is that I'm finding a good notation to write this.

Comment: Well, then each pair of circles will give you a pair of intersections (or maybe less). The coordinates are easy to find. I still don't get what do you mean by representation.

Comment: The mathematical notation. Basically I want to express this concept by using the mathematical formalism instead to use the words. Thank you for the support.

Comment: Oh, _that_.  Well, I'd go with smth like $$\{X_k\}=\mathop{\bigcup}_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}\{O_i\cap O_j\}$$